# Google sign in button not responding

Tags: android, google-signin

My google sign in button dont respond.I click it but nothing happens.
Here is my MainActivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
private TextView mStatusTextView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mStatusTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso=new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();

    mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
            .build();
    SignInButton signInButton=(SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
         signInButton.setSize(signInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
}


private void signIn() {
    Intent signinIntent=Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    mStatusTextView.setText("You have signed in");
    startActivityForResult(signinIntent,RC_SIGN_IN);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;
        case R.id.sign_out_button:
            signOut();
            break;

    }
}


private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
    if (signedIn) {
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
      //  findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mStatusTextView.setText("You have signed out");

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      //  findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    updateUI(false);
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
   // Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        mStatusTextView.setText("You Have Signed IN "+acct.getDisplayName());
        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        mStatusTextView.setText("You Have NOT Signed ");
      //  updateUI(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

}
```

here is my activity_main.xml

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="121dp"
    android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:onClick="onClick" />
```

I cant figure out any way to make it work.
It dont respond to click while sign out buttons prints the text.

Comment: Does your textView change text to "You have signed in" when you click on sign in button?

Comment: No, It doesnt respond(No change in textview takeplace).

Comment: make 2 different onClick method and then try.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you already solved it, sorry for late reply.

I had similar experience using com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton. It looks like parameter android:onClick not work. I use Android Studio 3.1.3.

Modify your onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mStatusTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso=new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).requestEmail().build();

    mGoogleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
            .build();
    SignInButton signInButton=(SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
         signInButton.setSize(signInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);

    mPlusSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                 @Override
                                                 public void onClick(View view) {
                                                     onClick(view);
                                                 }
                                             }); // ADD THIS
}
```